# dbDenyWrite still in force after recordset closed

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have some code that gets a value from another table, then updates the value in the table. This code is in a loop that performs for each item in recordset based on another table. The code works the first time through but the next time it errors on the first line saying access is denied because the table is being held by another use or the user interface. The code uses DAO.

Anyone have a clue as to why the dbDenyWrite is still in force after closing the recordset and destroying its reference?

Here is a code snippet:

```
Set rsRR = DataDB.OpenRecordset("Railroads", dbOpenTable, dbDenyWrite)
rsRR.Index = "Railroads_RRIx"
rsRR.Seek "=", RTrs!RR
If rsRR.NoMatch Then
    '   Write ERROR MESSAGE
    rsRR.Close
    Set rsRR = Nothing
    GoSub CleanUp
    ReverseRouteDataCollect = 0
    Exit Function
End If
If Not dWork Is Nothing Then Set dWork = Nothing
Set dWork = New Scripting.Dictionary
FieldsSave dWork, rsRR
i = FieldsCopy(drr, dWork, "TemplatesRailroad")
If dWork(rsRR.Name & "$LastWaybillNo") = "999999" Then
    rsRR.Edit
        rsRR!LastWaybillNo = 2001
    rsRR.Update
Else
    rsRR.Edit
        rsRR!LastWaybillNo = dWork(rsRR.Name & "$LastWaybillNo") + 1
    rsRR.Update
End If
rsRR.Close
Set rsRR = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

> .. why the dbDenyWrite is still in force after closing the recordset
>   and destroying its reference?

Because you only do this in case of a NoMatch.

So either change the dbDenyWrite to allow for edits, or (slower) reset the recordset before starting editing it:

```
Set rsRR = DataDB.OpenRecordset("Railroads", dbOpenTable)
```